# Reference an appended variable?

Tags: bash

How can I do this in a bash script?

```
#!/bin/sh

func() {
export ${NAME}_SUFFIX=`result_of_some_command`
}

NAME=my_name
func

# This variable will become my_name_SUFFIX
# but how can I reference it using $NAME?

echo ${${NAME}_SUFFIX}     # Doesn't work...
```

I'd use *declare* if it would work through function calls, but it seems it doesn't. Also, my version of declare doesn't support -x.

Comment: `declare -x` has been supported since at least `bash` 2.0.2.

Comment: Sorry, I meant -g.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know what you're trying to do...**warning**..."eval" is a terrible way to do it and variable indirection is better.  But, here is what you asked for.

One simple change to your script:

Change "export" to "eval" and it'll work.  You were most of the way there!
Oh, and change your "echo" statement as shown below.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/sh

func() {
eval ${NAME}_SUFFIX=`result_of_some_command`
}

NAME=my_name
func

# This variable will become my_name_SUFFIX
# but how can I reference it using $NAME?

eval echo "\${${NAME}_SUFFIX}"
```

Comment: I just want to stress again; variable indirection is the better way to do this.  But, again, here is what you asked for.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @emperor, you bet.  If it's the answer you were looking for don't forget to mark the question as answered.  Take care!

Answer (score 3):

You can use indirect parameter expansion:

```
varname=${NAME}_SUFFIX
echo "${!varname}"
```

---

`bash` 4.3 also introduced namerefs, which are a little simpler to use.

```
$ NAME=FOO
$ FOO_SUFFIX=3
$ declare -n varname=${NAME}_SUFFIX
$ echo $varname
3
```

Comment: Yes, but then I could have used varname to begin with:
    export varname=`result_of_some_command`

I need it in the $\${NAME}_SUFFIX} 'ish form.

Comment: `varname` is used outside of `func`. Its value is the name of the variable whose value you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need variable indirection, which is introduced with a `!` :

```
var_name=test
test=value
echo ${var_name}  # will echo test
echo ${!var_name} # will echo value
```