# bash bad substitution - access an environment variable from another

Tags: bash

How can I access an environment variable from another?  I have the following in my shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

export A_version=1.0.0

component=A

echo ${${component}_version}}
```

the bash script after the run gives me

```
temp.sh: line 9: ${${component}_version}}: bad substitution
```

Comment: that works if you want to simply echo the content of ${component}_version.  now how can I assign the value to another variable. something like

b=`eval "echo \$${component}_version"` ?  
would that work?

Comment: actually it looks like version=`eval "echo \\$${component}_version"` works.

Comment: Works only if you trust the variable's contents not to be malicious. If `component='(rm -rf ~)'`, then you're in a very bad place when you run that. Other (non-`eval`-based) parameter expansion syntax doesn't carry those risks. See also [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) re: why `eval` is generally discouraged.

Comment: I've looked at the myriad resources you linked to but I can't actually find a working code example for solving the OP's problem that doesn't use `eval`.  How about you post an answer here with one?

Comment: The alleged duplicates to the this question do not address how one would add a suffix like `_version` to the variable name before accessing it, so this should be reponed.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, ...I added a duplicate that specifically speaks to suffixing variables: [Reference an appended variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192093/reference-an-appended-variable) -- note that the author of the accepted answer suggests it not be used; [the answer by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37192243/14122) is the best-practice approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to do this.  Here is a working version of your script that prints `1.0.0`:

```
export A_version=1.0.0
component=A
eval "echo \$${component}_version"
```

For more information, see this page:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html

**Update:**  A safer way to do the same thing in Bash would be:

```
export A_version=1.0.0
component=A
var=${component}_version; echo "${!var}"
```

Note that you have to run this script with `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: Please don't encourage `eval` for indirect evaluation, *or* encourage the ABS as a reference -- it's very much the W3Schools of bash; half of what we do in the freenode #bash channel is help people unlearn bad habits they picked up there. [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) is a reference on indirect variable use that's more actively focused on best practices.  The bash-hackers' wiki also [covers indirection in its page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection).

Comment: Searching for "indirect expansion" in [the relevant manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) also works.

Comment: None of your suggestions seem to solve the OP's problem, how about you post your own answer?

Comment: The linked duplicates solve the OP's problem -- see the list at the top of the question. Accordingly, this question has been closed, and is not open to new answers.

Comment: How about posting a comment with the code?  What exactly would you put on line 3 of my script?

Comment: `var=${component}_version; echo "${!var}"`

Comment: ...that technique is literally described in at least one answer to every single question I linked.